# Where to add Respons.Redirect?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, button, passwords, response.redirect

I am trying to figure out where I would add my Response.Redirect("userAdmin.aspx) to my code. I have tried many different variations but the submit button does nothing. I am trying to understand where to put it. Can anyone help? I would greatly appreciate it!

here is my code

```
Protected Sub butSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles butSubmit.Click

    Dim myReader As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim mySqlConnection As Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim mySqlCommand As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    'Establish the SqlConnection by using the configuration manager to get the connection string in our web.config file.

    mySqlConnection = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings  ("ConnectionString").ToString())
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT password FROM MyUsers WHERE username = '" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "'"
    mySqlCommand = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, mySqlConnection)



    Try

        mySqlConnection.Open()
        myReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

        If (myReader.HasRows) Then
            myReader.Read()
            Dim password As String = myReader("password")
            If (password = Me.TextBox2.Text) Then
                'Open page with users and roles
                Dim message As String = "Correct password"
                Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly
                Dim title As String = "Authenticated"
                MsgBox(message, style, title)

            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
    Finally
        If Not (myReader Is Nothing) Then
            myReader.Close()
        End If

        If (mySqlConnection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open) Then
            mySqlConnection.Close()
        End If

   End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: MsgBox and Console in asp.net application ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Response.Redirect` outside of the `Try-Catch`, otherwise you'll get an `ThreadAbortException`. You can also use the overload [`Response.Redirect(url, false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

You should **use parameters** for your sql-command to prevent sql-injection!

```
Protected Sub butSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles butSubmit.Click
    Dim correctPassword As Boolean = False
    Using mySqlConnection = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT password FROM MyUsers WHERE username = @userName"
        Using mySqlCommand = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, mySqlConnection)
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", Me.TextBox1.Text)
            Try
                mySqlConnection.Open()
                Using myReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
                    If myReader.Read() Then
                        Dim password As String = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("password"))
                        If password = Me.TextBox2.Text Then
                            correctPassword = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    If correctPassword Then
        Response.Redirect("userAdmin.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
```

I would also strongly recommend to use [**ASP.NET-Membership**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thank you for what you have provided but it still does not lead to the new page, nothing happens when I enter the user name, "mcobery" and the password, "password and click submit take a look for yourself with this link. http://comweb.uml.edu/spepp18614/project1/Default.aspx

Comment: The code you provided seems much more logical however, I am sorry for my mistakes, I am very new to this.

Comment: Use the debugger to see what happens. Just set a breakpoint in the method, then press F10 to go to the next line inspecting all variable-values(f.e. `correctPassword`).

Comment: I debugged and inspected to no avail. Do you have any more suggestions? If you do not, it is totally ok.

Comment: @user1690599: What was the result of the debugging? You are the only one who knows `TextBox2.Text` or `myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("password"))` and why they are different or whatelse happens in  this method. The dedugger will definitely tell you the reason for this issue, we can't. Set also a breakpoint in the `Catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected void Button_Click(object sender,ClickEventArgs e)
    {
       Response.Redirect("userAdmin.aspx) ;
    }
```

frist try this for another button and see if the page is been redirected or not.. and if your not having ant problem then place after finally or inside finally depending on your criteria